Mid 80's animated movie about a boy and a talking donkey
I do not remember a lot about this movie but it has stuck with me.
A little boy got a gift from the moon or some kind of moon goddess.
He got a talking donkey
and two stallions and riches.
His brothers stole the horses and riches and went to to town.
The movie ends with the little boy possibly marrying a princess.
It was in the mid to late 80's. 
Any help at all would be so very much appreciated!!

@Stacey FWIW, the horses have yellow manes and tails in the movie suggested in my answer below.

I wonder if this is the animated Russian movie The Humpbacked Horse (AKA Konyok Gorbunok). It's originally from 1947, but was re-released in 1975 and a dubbed version was released in the US in 1977 under the name The Magic Pony (still a few years away from the 80s, though). In it, a boy talks to the stars and a yellow-maned horse comes down from the sky and gives the boy two beautiful black stallions and a smaller, humpbacked gray horse that talks (and might be mistaken for a donkey). His brothers steal the stallions and head to the city. The boy and his humpbacked horse go after them and have some adventures together. It also ends with the boy, now a handsome man, marrying a moon princess. You can watch the entire movie here on Youtube.
